# inequality strong induction proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I understand everything up to the induction hypothesis in this worksheet of mine. I don't understand why you were able to substitute in values of 3 for all the a's in the induction hypothesis. Can someone explain the answer to me by any chance.

here is the question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B99UJ.jpg

and here's the supposed answer I don't understand: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTlK1.jpg

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! Please replace the images of text by actual text, where formulas are typed using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also consider reading [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to improve the quality of this and future posts. As of now, your question is likely to attract down votes.

Answer (score 0):

They did not substitute the $a_k$ for $3$. They used the statements $P(k)$, $P(k-1)$ and $P(k-2)$, those are:
$$
a_k < 3^k,\quad a_{k-1} < 3^{k-1},\quad a_{k-2} < 3^{k-2}.
$$
Hence, they conclude that
$$
a_{k+1} = \underbrace{a_k}_{<3^k} + \underbrace{a_{k-1}}_{<3^{k-1}} + \underbrace{a_{k-2}}_{<3^{k-2}} < 3^k + 3^{k-1} + 3^{k-2}.
$$